# I'm encountering a MySQL error indicating a missing column. However in phpMyAdmin the mentioned column is visibly present in the database

Tags: mysql, vbulletin

I've successfully installed an older forum script, VBulletin 2, on my hosting environment with PHP4. While I acknowledge the potential security concerns associated with using PHP4, my intention is to revive one of my initial forums that I created.

Nevertheless, the forum functions smoothly, allowing me to perform all the necessary operations. However, I encounter errors when attempting to access the User Panel.

> Database error in vBulletin 2.3.11:
>
> Invalid SQL: SELECT privatemessage.*,touser.username AS tousername,fromuser.username AS fromusername,icon.title AS icontitle,icon.iconpath
>
> FROM privatemessage,user AS touser,user AS fromuser
>
> LEFT JOIN icon ON icon.iconid=privatemessage.iconid
>
> WHERE privatemessage.userid='1'
>
> AND folderid=0
>
> AND touser.userid=privatemessage.touserid
>
> AND fromuser.userid=privatemessage.fromuserid
>
> AND messageread=0
> ORDER BY dateline DESC
>
>
> mysql error: Unknown column 'privatemessage.iconid' in 'on clause'
> mysql error number: 1054

I can post a new thread but when I answer to it I get this error:

```
Database error in vBulletin 2.3.11:
Invalid SQL: SELECT user.*, style.templatesetid
            FROM subscribethread,user,usergroup
                LEFT JOIN style ON (IF(user.styleid=0, 1, user.styleid)=style.styleid)
            WHERE subscribethread.threadid='1'
            AND subscribethread.userid=user.userid
            AND usergroup.usergroupid=user.usergroupid
            AND user.userid<>'1'
            AND user.usergroupid<>'3'
            AND usergroup.canview = 1
            AND user.lastactivity>'1703928997'

mysql error: Unknown column 'user.styleid' in 'on clause'
mysql error number: 1054
```

Upon inspecting through PhpMyAdmin, I verified that the columns do indeed exist. Despite this confirmation, I'm puzzled about the root cause of the issue. Can anyone provide assistance or insights?

I tried to recreate the column and also changing the order but nothing happened.

Comment: Use a JOIN on all but the first of your table references

Comment: I am not an expert with mysql, how to do it?

Comment: ' If you mix comma joins with the other join types when there is a join condition, an error of the form Unknown column 'col_name' in 'on clause' may occur. ' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Comment: Then you have some learning to do. There are lots of helpful sites out there to help you learn SQL. [For example this one](https://www.mariadbtutorial.com/mariadb-basics/mariadb-inner-join/) look at the other pages as well as the one references

Comment: I tried this but still not working: SELECT
    privatemessage.*,
    (SELECT username FROM user WHERE userid = privatemessage.touserid) AS tousername,
    (SELECT username FROM user WHERE userid = privatemessage.fromuserid) AS fromusername,
    (SELECT title FROM icon WHERE iconid = privatemessage.iconid) AS icontitle,
    (SELECT iconpath FROM icon WHERE iconid = privatemessage.iconid) AS iconpath
FROM
    privatemessage
WHERE
    privatemessage.userid = '1'
    AND privatemessage.folderid = 0
    AND privatemessage.messageread = 0
ORDER BY
    privatemessage.dateline DESC;

Answer (score 0):

You combine comma-style JOIN and explicit JOIN. Comma-style JOIN have less priority then explicit JOIN. So your

```
FROM subscribethread,user,usergroup
LEFT JOIN style ON (IF(user.styleid=0, 1, user.styleid)=style.styleid)
```

is by fact

```
FROM subscribethread,user,
(
                          usergroup
LEFT JOIN style ON (IF(user.styleid=0, 1, user.styleid)=style.styleid)
)
```

and it is obvious that in the added parenthesis the reference to `user` table (which is outer for added parenthesis) is not legal.

The most simple fix - replace a comma with `CROSS JOIN`:

```
FROM subscribethread
CROSS JOIN user
CROSS JOIN usergroup
LEFT JOIN style ON (IF(user.styleid=0, 1, user.styleid)=style.styleid)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried to run this query:

FROM `subscribethreadid`
CROSS JOIN user
CROSS JOIN usergroup
LEFT JOIN style ON (IF(user.styleid=0, 1, user.styleid)=style.styleid) 

but I got an error, can you tell me how to run it properly?

Comment: @MatteoRusso Do you want me to predict the error message which you have got?

Comment: I am sorry, I thought I pasted the error in the previous comment. Anyway that's it: Statement type not recognized. (near "FROM" at position 0)

Comment: @MatteoRusso you need to add the select ... part in front of the from ... part. The answer focuses on the part of the sql statement that causes the error.